# How to find the item with the closest distance in a huge list of items while still having Hash functionality?

Tags: java, data-structures, hash

I have a long list of Vertices and their id's. I want to give their id's to a method and get the Vertices in a fast way because there are a lot of them, linear search takes too long.

I am doing this with `HashSet<long id, Vertex v>` for now, I also want to find the closest vertex to the coordinates I give to the method like find [X.XXXX, Y.YYYY] by comparing `Vertex.getCoordinates()` I want to do this in an efficient manner, which structure should I choose to use? Also calculate distance method requires sqrt(), I can use sqrDist() but still I want to improve.

I am planning to have a sorted list-like structure in parallel(at this point
I choose time over space) and do a binarySearch() then return the closest one like that, is this a valid solution?
How can I make Java use binarySearch() without implementing it on my own?

Comment: maybe you should look towards spatial hashing or quadtree
https://github.com/ProjectBarks/quadtree-versus-spatialhash

Comment: Linear approch will give `O(n)` time complexity. For `n` searches, `O(n*n)`. Whereas for binary search approch it depends. It depends on list (if list is constant) then  sort will take `O(n*log(n))`. Then on same sorted list, for n searches, time complexity would be `O(n*(log(n)))`. If this is what you are thinking of then yes that's valid solution. But if list changes after each search then each time you would sort list and search. This would be worse than linear search as time complexity would be `O(n*n*log(n))` due to `n` sorts